# Unable to groupby the column and return the department name, with no of employees respectively and salary range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**Unable to groupby the column and return the department name, with no of employees respectively and salary range.**

Actual DataFrame is :

```
    Name      Dept     Salary   RcvDate
0   Vertie    IT        3000    2018-08-05
1   Charlsie  IT        2000    2018-08-05
2   Manual    IT        4000    2018-08-05
3   Trudi     IT        6000    2018-08-05
4   Chong     IT        5600    2018-08-05
7   Deedee    IT        20000   2018-08-06
8   Ramonita  Admin     9500    2018-08-06
9   Terica    Admin     8900    2018-08-06
10  Hyman     Admin     7200    2018-08-06
11  Alysha    Admin     4400    2018-08-06
13  Mackenzie Admin     8700    2018-08-06
14  Amparo    Admin     9100    2018-08-06
15  Tabitha   Admin     6500    2018-08-06
16  Burl      Admin     6000    2018-08-06
17  Pok       Admin     5600    2018-08-06
18  Junie     Admin     9500    2018-08-06
19  Rodrick   Admin     8900    2018-08-06
20  Maryln    Support   7200    2018-08-06
21  Tina      Support   4400    2018-08-07
22  Wilson    Support   6500    2018-08-07
```

I'm attaching the code below

```
dataset.drop_duplicates(subset=['Dept'], keep='first')
```

The output is :

```
    Name      Dept     Salary   RcvDate
0   Vertie    IT        3000    2018-08-05
8   Ramonita  Admin     9500    2018-08-06
20  Maryln    Support   7200    2018-08-06
```

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with named aggregations:

```
df = df.groupby('Dept').agg(Count = ('Name','size'),
                            Min = ('Salary','min'),
                            Max = ('Salary','max'))
```